# node js builtin os function find

Tags: node.js, shelljs

I'm using the [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) npm package for file traversal:

```js
var shell = require('shelljs');
cFilesOnly = function (file, idx) { return (file.includes('.c')); }
excludeIrrelevantDir = function (file, idx) { return !file.includes('DDD'); }
var files = shell.find('.').filter(cFilesOnly).filter(excludeIrrelevantDir);
console.log(files);
```

The package works great:

```
$ tree
.
├── AAA
│   └── main.c
├── BBB
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── go.c
│   └── run.c
├── DDD
│   └── bad.c
└── main.js

4 directories, 6 files
$ node main.js
[ 'AAA/main.c', 'BBB/go.c', 'BBB/run.c' ]
```

- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) reported `1 high severity vulnerability` in that package, so
- I want to replace that package with a *native node os* alternative.
- I looked ([here](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html)) but didn't get very far - what am I missing?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/fs.html readDir, stat

Comment: However, I will tell you that `node.js` in my experience has been slower than using `execFile` to run powershell or linux commands for the same thing. I'd run your own tests if you're working with more than ~100 nested directories (e.g. making a drive scan)

Comment: @CodyＧ it seems the `readdir` is *not* recursive, so unless I'm missing something (?) this os needs to be wrapped and managed

Comment: Yes, I mean... if you want native there is quite a bit of work to do. Perhaps a different package meets your need?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob